# ColdFusion Get List of Docs in a Folder - Collection

Tags: google-docs-api

If I follow the examples I have seen to get the doc items in a collection, I end up with the below.  It does bring back one entry but its not the items in the folder its just the folder entry itself.

`<cfhttp            url="https://docs.google.com/feeds/documents/private/full/folder%3A0B_xSYw8SWKixSxxx/contents" method="get" result="result" charset="utf-8">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="GoogleLogin auth=#getAuth(variables.docservice)#">`

If I send in 
https://docs.google.com/feeds/documents/private/full?showfolders=true
I get all my docs and a listing of folders.

Am I missing something?

Comment: <cfhttp url="https://docs.google.com/feeds/documents/private/full/folder%3A0B_xSYw8SWKixSjdzTngyXxxx/contents" method="get" result="result" charset="utf-8">
 <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="GoogleLogin auth=#getAuth(variables.docservice)#">
  
</cfhttp>

Comment: I have discovered that you do not need /contents to get the item listing. https://docs.google.com/feeds/folders/private/full/folder%3A0B_xSYw8SWKixY0hQTDJoalRZbGM  gives me all the items.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this correctly then you need to use a different tag.

```
<cfdirectory 
directory = "directory name"
action = "list"
name = "query_name"
sort = "asc"
type = "all">
<cfdump var="#query_name#"/>
```